# SSIS Control Flow: Wait till all tasks complete

Tags: ssis, control-flow

I have an SSIS ETL flow that takes data from 3 tables in Database A and copies some of the columns of each table into corresponding tables of Database B. Each of the 3 copy tasks are represented by one Data Flow, therefore I have 3 Data Flow tasks in my Control Flow, all running in parallel.

At the end of it all, I want the ability to send an email in the success case, and a different email in the failure case. When there is only one data flow task, creating this behavior is obvious.

How do I make a control flow task waits till 3 parallel tasks are complete and evaluates the collective success of each task as flow 1 AND flow 2 AND flow 3 are success, and evaluates the collective failure as flow 1 OR flow 2 OR flow 3 are failure?

I am just trying to send 1 email after this all that is a success email if ALL complete successfully or sends a failure email if AT LEAST 1 fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use precedence constraints at control flow level.

[image]

Double click the precedence constraint and setup either all success or at least one failure.

**All Success**

[image]

**At Least One Failure**

[image]

Comment: Oh my gosh I can't believe how fast you put together that answer and answered this question!